# Navigation bar not collapsing when tested on a mobile device

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just created a vertical bootstrap navigation bar and it looking like this:

[image]

Now my problem is when I test the app on a phone, instead of collapsing, it just disappear and the 3 lines does not appear.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="sidebar-menu">
            <li class="header">MAIN MENU</li>

            <li class="treeview">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"> Home</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
                        <li class="treeview">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"> Patients</span>
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="treeview">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"> Appointments</span>
                <span class="label label-primary pull-right">4</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="widgets.html">
                <i class="fa fa-th"></i> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"> Daily Reports</span> <!--<small class="label pull-right bg-green">income reports</small>-->
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="widgets.html">
                <i class="fa fa-th"></i> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"> Monthly Reports</span> <!--<small class="label pull-right bg-green">income reports</small>-->
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="treeview">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-pie-chart"></i>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"> Debts</span>
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="treeview">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"> Outlay</span>
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
              </a>

            </li>
            <li class="treeview">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-table"></i> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-scale"> Statistics</span>
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="treeview">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-table"></i> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"> Equipments/Tools</span>
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you intentionally not pasted your `button` code in your question?

If not, you should also have the following:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#uniqueid" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

You'll also want to add an `id` to your menu wrapper:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="uniqueid">
```

Comment: no of course, not intentionally. I will test it now and lets see

Comment: It could be to do with a few things... Have you followed this: [http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar). Might be to do with your wrapping `<nav>`

Comment: yeah. If you want I can post the code of all the page here, or sending it to you by email

Comment: @androidnation if you could revise your question to include all code applicable (i.e. - everything within your nav element and any custom CSS you've applied) that'd be great.